# How to check if a time noted is within designated window or range in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to check if a time of collection is within allowed time window or not.

For e.g.

```
    A         B               C
1 10.36     10.30     1 min out of +/- 5 minutes window   
2 10.24     10.30     1 min out of +/- 5 minutes window
```

A1 here time of collection of data, and B1 is the scheduled time. The acceptable window or range for this is +/- 5 minutes out of window. In this case the time of collection is 1 min out of +/- 5 minutes window. Similar example is shown in row 2. How can i get C1 to show the message as above which can account for + 5 minutes and - 5 minutes scenarios?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ABS(A1-B1)>(5/1440),"Problem!","OK")
```

5/1440 is 5 minutes (1440 minutes in a full day)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use this formula¹ in C1 and fill down as necessary,

   ```
   =ROUND(MAX((ABS(A1-B1)-0.05)*100, 0), 0)
   ```
2. Use the following custom number format on column C,

   ```
   0 \mi\n out of ± 5 \mi\nut\e wi\n\dow
   ```

The advantages of a custom number format is that the numbers remain numbers and are available for future calculations (e.g. SUM, AVERAGE, etc) while displaying the text you wish to show. Note the right-alignment in the cells indicating true numbers.

[image]

¹ <sub>This formula depends on the time values being mixed numbers and not true time. If the time values are true time with a non-EN-US number format then additional maths may have to be applied to the formula.</sub>

Comment: thank you Jeeped. But i am seeing the deviation as -4 min instead of the 5 minutes for the times (incl dates) below.                                                                               =ROUND((ABS(S2-K2)-0.05)*100, 0)                 9/30/17 9:50
                                                                            9/30/17 10:00

Comment: @HN_seeker - Just realized it myself. See edit above.

Comment: @TimWilliams - ... and I forgot to have a floor so that 4 minutes showed as zero!

Comment: =ROUND(MAX((ABS(S2-K2)-0.05)*100, 0),0)                                                       this is showing as 0mins now      for the time difference between 950 and 1000  on 30Sep2017

Comment: If two times are 7 minutes apart then they are 2 minutes outside of a ±5 minute window; if two times are 3 minutes apart then they are zero minutes outside of a ±5 minute window.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, there are basically two times only. 9.50 and 10.00. the date was included as an addendum. this should be 5 minutes out of +/- 5 minutes window.

Comment: Your example in the original question shows 0.06 being 1 minute outside of a 5 minute window; your example in the above comment (e.g. 9.50 and 10.00) should be 45 minutes outside, not 5 minutes outside. If your latter example is correct, anyone with elementary school maths skills should be able to adjust the formula.

Comment: thank you both.I used both your suggestions and it worked.